# Which string will break?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

A mass is hanging from a string that is attached
to the ceiling. A second piece of string (identical
to the first) hangs from the lower end of the
mass
State and explain which string will break if:
a the bottom string is slowly pulled with ever
increasing force
b the bottom string is very abruptly pulled down.

For a the answer is that the top will break. Is it because there is already a downwards force on the top string so when you slowly increase the force on the bottom string it increases the downwards force on the top string? Since the top string had more downwards force acting on it to begin with (from the weight of the mass) then it breaks sooner.

For b the answer is that the bottom breaks first. I'm having trouble with this one but my guess is that because the force is applied over such a short time then it breaks the bottom string before the downwards force can even reach the top string, thus preventing it from breaking?

Can someone please let me know if my answers are correct? If not, could you please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: This experiment is easy enough to replicate with thread and a weight, in a home environment.

Comment: @planckton Yes, you are correct. When the lower string is pulled slowly the tension in the upper string is always greater than in the lower string because the upper string must support the weight of the hanging mass as well. If the strings have the same strength then the upper string breaks first. However, because of the inertia of the hanging mass, it takes a short time for a change in tension to be transferred from the lower string to the upper string. So if the lower string is pulled hard enough and quickly enough, then it will break before its tension is transferred to the upper string.

Comment: @gandalf61 Thank you for letting me know! Your response was very helpful in making sure I understood the concept.